# How does [ ] work in a function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

How does [] work in a function in Clojure?

```
(def square (fn [x] (* x x)))
(square 10) ; -> 100
```

As I understand from the above, we pass 10 in the place of x. Shouldn't I be able to do the following?

```
(def square (fn [x y] (* x y)))
(square 5 10) ; -> 50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Clojure, `[]` is used to represent the argument list.  That is to say, the anonymous function defined in `square` takes a single argument and multiplies it against itself.

You can *absolutely* extend that, but you're probably going to want to change the name of the function to better reflect what it's actually doing instead.

```
(def multiply (fn [x y] (* x y)))
```

Comment: not sure why but when I run `(multiply 10 5)` it throws an error `Attempting to call unbound fn`, I'm using http://www.tryclj.com/ to learn the language, maybe the problem is with the repl...

Comment: It's probably an issue with the their REPL.  I'm using Light Table locally and the result is as you would expect it to be.  Or, you could give it a moment and try again.  It seemed to work the second attempt around.

Comment: Just tried that on TryClj, works as expected. Something must be wrong with what you did before in that same REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on [Makoto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458688/1562315).

You don't need to name a function in order to use it:

```
((fn [x] (* x x)) 10) ; 100

((fn [x y] (* x y)) 5 10) ; 50
```

Anonymous functions often crop up as arguments to *higher order function*s such as `map`.

Clojure (and other Lisps) separate the act of making a function as a thing from the act of naming it. `def` does the naming. A subsequent `def` for a name erases/obliterates/overwrites an earlier one.

Nor do you need to explicate a function in order to name it. Instead of

```
(def multiply (fn [x y] (* x y)))
```

just write

```
(def multiply *)
```

There's a lovely explanation of this (for Common Lisp) in Paul Graham's [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html).